# NPE on @Value and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I have an javafx + spring app.

The application listening serial port, reading data and shows it to UI.
The problem caused by NPE with Controller class on outputLoggerFile and serialPort on same class.

This is my configuration file with PropertySource so my environment should know about these propoperties. 
**SpringConfig**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:com.properties", "classpath:application.properties"})
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public SerialPort serialPort(@Value("${serialPort.portName}") String portName){
        return new SerialPort(portName);
    }

    @Bean
    public AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter(){
        AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter = new AnnotationMBeanExporter();
        annotationMBeanExporter.addExcludedBean("dataSource");
        return annotationMBeanExporter;
    }
}
```

This class class setting my properties to the SerialPort object, injects EventListener class  and openning connection. Works fine.
**ComReader**

```
@Scope("singletone")
@Component
public class ComReader {

    @Autowired
    private EventListener eventListener;

    @Autowired
    public SerialPort serialPort;

    @Value("${serialPort.baudRate}")
    private int baudRate;
    @Value("${serialPort.dataBits}")
    private int dataBits;
    @Value("${serialPort.stopBits}")
    private int stopBits;
    @Value("${serialPort.parity}")
    private int parity;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Opening port: " + serialPort.getPortName());
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(baudRate,dataBits,stopBits,parity);
            serialPort.addEventListener(eventListener, 1);
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem class everything work fine except any classes/fields which i want inject here.

**Controller**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    @Value("${logger.outputFilePath}")
    private String outputLoggerFile;

    private SerialPort serialPort;

    @Autowired
    public void setSerialPort(SerialPort serialPort) {
        this.serialPort = serialPort;
    }


    private static ObservableList<CallDetailRecord> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @FXML
    void initialize(){

        Timer scheduler = new Timer();
        scheduler.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (serialPort.isOpened()) circlePortStatus.setFill(Color.GREEN); //(NPE HERE)
                else circlePortStatus.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        }, 5_000, 60_000);





        counterCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        startTimeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startTime"));
        stopTimeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stopTime"));
        numberACol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("numberB"));
        numberBCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("numberA"));
        rescodeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("resultCode"));
        subACol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("subscriberB"));
        subBCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("subscriberA"));
        table.setItems(list);

        Label webLinkLabel = new Label("Веб ресурс");
        AppStart appStart = new AppStart();
        webLinkLabel.setOnMouseClicked(event -> appStart.getHostServices().showDocument(getURLPropertie()));
        webLink.setGraphic(webLinkLabel);

        Label logsLinkLabel = new Label("Логи");
        logsLinkLabel.setOnMouseClicked(event -> appStart.getHostServices().showDocument(outputLoggerFile));   //(NPE HERE)
        logsLink.setGraphic(logsLinkLabel);

    }

    public void addCdr(CallDetailRecord cdr){
        list.add(cdr);
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CallDetailRecord::getId).reversed());
    }

    private String getURLPropertie(){
        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties")).getFile())){
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(is);
            return prop.getProperty("url.link");
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "https://google.com";
    }
}
```

This is the code that loads and displays the FXML:

```
this.primaryStage = primaryStage; 
Platform.setImplicitExit(false); 
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/primal.fxml")); 
primaryStage.setTitle("NIIAR"); 
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/icon.png")); 
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1400, 900)); 
createTray(); 
primaryStage.show();
```

If im trying to debug in other class that using Controller its shows the variable outputLoggerFile contains my propertie. I dont have any idea why.

sources - https://github.com/mindgame73/CDRListener-FX

Comment: Are you sure the spring application context (bean factory) is managing your `Controller ` instance? Can you show the code that configures the `FXMLLoader` to do that?

Comment: `this.primaryStage = primaryStage;`
        `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);`
        `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/primal.fxml"));`
        `primaryStage.setTitle("NIIAR");`
        ` primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/icon.png"));`
        `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1400, 900));`
        `createTray();`
        `primaryStage.show();`

I guess it's not. But my controller is managing UI, the classic way to annotate this controller won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the `FXMLLoader` is to create a controller by instantiating the class specified in the `fx:controller` attribute of the FXML file (invoking its no-argument constructor); then it injects `@FXML`-annotated fields into the controller, and after it parses the FXML file, it calls the `initialize()` method (if there is one).

Since the controller is instantiated by directly invoking its constructor, the Spring application context knows nothing about it, and can't inject any `@Autowired` beans into it.

To fix this, you need to set a `controllerFactory` on the `FXMLLoader`, instructing it to "create" (really retrieve) the controller instance from the Spring `ApplicationContext`. The controller factory is basically just a function (a `@FunctionalInterface`) which takes a `Class<?>` and produces an object. Since this is exactly the signature of one of the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` methods,  the code for this looks like:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/primal.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

where `context` is the Spring `ApplicationContext` (you may need to jump through some hoops to get a reference to this in the method where you load your FXML file; usually just creating a field for it and annotating the field `Autowired` works).

I would make a couple of tweaks to the configuration of the controller class, too. By default, Spring manages beans as singleton scope. This is definitely not what you want here: if you were to load the same FXML a second time, you would need a different controller instance (as you would have a different set of UI controls). So you definitely need to scope the controller as a prototype.

Secondly, the Spring `@Controller` stereotype is intended for controllers in the Spring MVC sense; so I don't think it's really what you want here (though I don't think it does any harm). I would annotate the controller class as

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.PROTOTYPE_SCOPE)
public class Controller { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: really appreciate that